# Pow function in curry

Tags: curry

I'm working with curry, and I'm using pakcs 2.2.1, and if I write 2^2

I get this error

```
2^2

PAKCS_Main_Exp.curry, line 2.18: Error:
    `^' is undefined
ERROR occurred during parsing!
```

If I use the most recent version of pakcs (3.3.0) I don't have this problem, unfortunately, I only can work with 2.2.1 version.

Do you know if I need to load a module or how I can do this operation?

(2*2 is not an option, because I need to work with very big numbers)

Thanks in advance